# Pass class type as argument to class constructor

Tags: python, python-class

Say I have a `Directory` class which accepts a list of other sub-directories as an argument:

```
class File:
    pass

class Directory:
    def __init__(self, directories: List[Directory], files: List[File]):
                                         ^^^^^^^^^
        self.directories = directories
        self.files = files
```

I am getting an error saying `"Directory" is not defined`. This code works just fine if I don't pass the types, but how do you handle this use-case in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a recursive typing definition. This can be achieved in Python by providing a string with the name of the type, rather than the type itself.

```py
class File:
   pass

class Directory:
   def __init__(self, directories: List['Directory'], files: List[File]):
      self.directories = directories
      self.files = files
```

Comment: ah thank you - also another noob question: am I supposed to get any type validation when I create a Directory now? how come I still can make something like `d = Directory("string type", [])` with no error?

Comment: Typing in Python is a misleading name. Python *never* enforces types, because this goes against the duck typing principle. Typing should be understood as linting, because the only utility is to provide some context when you hover a function in your IDE. Python simply ignores that.

Comment: ah makes sense, so basically they are more of a "documentations"for the params. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class File:
   pass

class Directory:
   def __init__(self, directories: list[Directory], files: list[File]):
      self.directories = directories
      self.files = files
```

The import from `__future__` causes all types to converted to their string equivalents.  And in 3.10, you can use plain old `list` rather than `List`